# Get final URL after curl is redirected

Tags: linux, redirect, curl, wget

I need to get the final URL after a page redirect preferably with curl or wget.

For example *http://google.com* may redirect to *http://www.google.com*.

The contents are easy to get(ex. `curl --max-redirs 10 http://google.com -L`), but I'm only interested in the final url (in the former case http://www.google.com).

Is there any way of doing this by using only Linux built-in tools? (command line only)

Answer (score 330, accepted):

`curl`'s [`-w` option](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-verbose/usingcurl-writeout) and the sub variable `url_effective` is what you are
looking for.

Something like

```bash
curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} https://example.com
```

More info

```
-L         Follow redirects
-s         Silent mode. Don't output anything
-o FILE    Write output to <file> instead of stdout
-w FORMAT  What to output after completion
```

**More**

You might want to add [`-I`](http://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-I) (that is an uppercase `i`) as well, which will make the command not download any "body", but it then also uses the HEAD method, which is not what the question included and risk changing what the server does. Sometimes servers don't respond well to HEAD even when they respond fine to GET.

Comment: you should be able to use "-o /dev/null" if you don't want the file

Comment: That's more of a shell feature than curl

Comment: @DanielStenberg you need `-I` otherwise it will actually download the file.

Comment: doesn't work. `curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} https://goo dot gl/un5E ` outputs `https://goo dot gl/un5E` (replace `dot` with .)

Comment: Some websites also need a spoofed user agent with `curl -A ...` to redirect to the expected location.

Comment: Be aware that this might reveal/print your password as part of the URL if you are using a .netrc file (-n) for authentication. It might end up somewhere unexpected when using this in a script (e.g. in the insecure parameter list of another command).

Comment: Does this output query strings also? Like `?utm=x` ? Doesn't seem like it

Comment: Sure it does. The query part is part of the URL.

Comment: How come even with `-s` you need `-o /dev/null`

Comment: @minseong `-o /dev/null` suppresses the HTTP response from being outputted anywhere. `-s` is for curl's own output (like progress or errors) and specifically does not cover the HTTP response.

Comment: @SybillePeters : That's a  good bit of additional info on this topic, thanks!  .. BUT ... junkjunkjunk.com now produces a redirect. You can buy that domain if you want! To see the `6` return code, I added an `X` at the front of your url. Other readers may have to continue to distort that URL to create one that hasn't been harvested. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 42):

Thanks, that helped me. I made some improvements and wrapped that in a helper script "finalurl":

```
#!/bin/bash
curl "$1" -s -L -I -o /dev/null -w '%{url_effective}'
```

- `-o` output to `/dev/null`
- `-I` don't actually download, just discover the final URL
- `-s` silent mode, no progressbars

This made it possible to call the command from other scripts like this:

```
echo `finalurl http://someurl/`
```

Comment: Thanks for those ideas. I rewrote it for terminal usage in my .bashrc file as a function, and there's no need for the terse options in that file, so I used the long names to self-document this: `finalurl() { curl --silent --location --head --output /dev/null --write-out '%{url_effective}' -- "$@"; }`

Answer (score 11):

as another option:

```
$ curl -i http://google.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 19 Jun 2010 04:15:10 GMT
Expires: Mon, 19 Jul 2010 04:15:10 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

But it doesn't go past the first one.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you. I ended up implementing your suggestions: curl -i + grep

```
curl -i http://google.com -L | egrep -A 10 '301 Moved Permanently|302 Found' | grep 'Location' | awk -F': ' '{print $2}' | tail -1
```

Returns blank if the website doesn't redirect, but that's good enough for me as it works on consecutive redirections.

Could be buggy, but at a glance it works ok.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with wget usually.  `wget --content-disposition` "url" additionally if you add `-O /dev/null` you will not be actually saving the file.

`wget -O /dev/null --content-disposition example.com`

Comment: Replace from `-O /dev/null` to only `-O-`. Better: `wget -O- --content-disposition example.com`

Comment: wget -O /dev/null --content-disposition example.com and wget -O- /dev/null --content-disposition example.com produce a lot more output than the redirected URL. curl $1 -s -L -I -o /dev/null -w '%{url_effective}' works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

The parameters `-L (--location)` and `-I (--head)` still doing unnecessary HEAD-request to the location-url.

If you are sure that you will have no more than one redirect, it is better to disable follow location and use a curl-variable %{redirect_url}.

This code do only one HEAD-request to the specified URL and takes redirect_url from location-header:

```
curl --head --silent --write-out "%{redirect_url}\n" --output /dev/null "https://""goo.gl/QeJeQ4"
```

---

### Speed test

`all_videos_link.txt` - 50 links of goo.gl+bit.ly which redirect to youtube

#### 1. With follow location

```
time while read -r line; do
    curl -kIsL -w "%{url_effective}\n" -o /dev/null  $line
done < all_videos_link.txt
```

*Results:*

```
real    1m40.832s
user    0m9.266s
sys     0m15.375s
```

#### 2. Without follow location

```
time while read -r line; do
    curl -kIs -w "%{redirect_url}\n" -o /dev/null  $line
done < all_videos_link.txt
```

*Results:*

```
real    0m51.037s
user    0m5.297s
sys     0m8.094s
```

Comment: Seems pretty uncommon that you'd know in advance that there would only be one redirect ...

Comment: Thanks, actually your method was the only one that was able to give me the correct url from: https://www.breachbase.pwnedbook.com/leaks/facebook of all examples in this thread, that page redirects to a youtube url and is a "test" for see how many that is willing to click on the url for download a breach without checking the end of it, however  thanks to you i didn't become a victim of this test as 1 trillion others have become, according to the number of viewers on the youtube vid.. Respect! +1 of course.

// wuseman

Answer (score 4):

`curl` can only follow http redirects. To also follow meta refresh directives and javascript redirects, you need a full-blown browser like headless chrome:

```
#!/bin/bash
real_url () {
    printf 'location.href\nquit\n' | \
    chromium-browser --headless --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer \
    --disable-dev-shm-usage --no-sandbox --repl "$@" 2> /dev/null \
    | tr -d '>>> ' | jq -r '.result.value'
}
```

If you don't have chrome installed, you can use it from a docker container:

```
#!/bin/bash
real_url () {
    printf 'location.href\nquit\n' | \
    docker run -i --rm --user "$(id -u "$USER")" --volume "$(pwd)":/usr/src/app \
    zenika/alpine-chrome --no-sandbox --repl "$@" 2> /dev/null \
    | tr -d '>>> ' | jq -r '.result.value'
}
```

Like so:

```
$ real_url http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.pgeola.2020.06.005 
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0016787820300638?via%3Dihub
```

Answer (score 3):

This would work:

```
 curl -I somesite.com | perl -n -e '/^Location: (.*)$/ && print "$1\n"'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do it with curl, but libwww-perl installs the GET alias.

```
$ GET -S -d -e http://google.com
GET http://google.com --> 301 Moved Permanently
GET http://www.google.com/ --> 302 Found
GET http://www.google.ca/ --> 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Connection: close
Date: Sat, 19 Jun 2010 04:11:01 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Expires: -1
Client-Date: Sat, 19 Jun 2010 04:11:01 GMT
Client-Peer: 74.125.155.105:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=a1925ca9f8af11b9:TM=1276920661:LM=1276920661:S=ULFrHqOiFDDzDVFB; expires=Mon, 18-Jun-2012 04:11:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.ca
Title: Google
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with it?

```
#!/bin/bash 
LOCATION=`curl -I 'http://your-domain.com/url/redirect?r=something&a=values-VALUES_FILES&e=zip' | perl -n -e '/^Location: (.*)$/ && print "$1\n"'` 
echo "$LOCATION"
```

Note: when you execute the command curl -I http://your-domain.com have to use single quotes in the command like  `curl -I 'http://your-domain.com'`

Answer (score -5):

You could use grep. doesn't wget tell you where it's redirecting too? Just grep that out.