# Getting the URL of browser in PHP after redirection

Tags: php, url, redirect, curl

I have a URL for example xyz.com/123456. When I open it up in the browser, the url gets redirected to xyz.com/test_user, where 123456 is user id and test_user is the user name. I want to extract the 2nd URL after it gets redirected from the first.

I have written a script that would get a input of different user ids from a text file and generate the first URL. I want to run the URL, either in the browser or in some way via cmd, and obtain the redirected 2nd URL.
I have tried using EFFECTIVE_URL in Curl but it keeps returning the 1st URL. I have also tried $_SERVER but it returns the script file rather than the URL.

Is there any way so that I can get the URL entered in the browser window after redirection? 
Or maybe without even opening the URL in the browser can I get the redirected URL?

Comment: TRY TO USE print_r($_SERVER); and check

Comment: I think you can use `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]` or something like that. Just dump `$_SERVER` and check.

Comment: Are you redirecting it with .htaccess, or in PHP?

Comment: REDIRECT_URL does not work. It gives me the local address

Comment: @JohnnyFaldo, I am redirecting using php. The link I give as input in header gets redirected once more. I need that URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's three settings that will help you get the redirection URL a bit faster (without having to actually wait for curl to redirect you)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); //don't follow the redirect
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // do return the transfer
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);         // do show the header

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); //either get the certificates, or just disable checking
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Then, when you finally execute the request, you can find the redirection from a header match.

```
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/4?_rdr=p'; //remember to add ?_rdr=p to the end of your URL

$response = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $response, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Your URL should be in `$matches[0]`.

Comment: `$ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $content);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); // Must be set to true so that PHP follows any "Location:" header
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $response = curl_exec($ch); // $a will contain all headers

  preg_match_all('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $response, $matches);
  $url = $matches[0];
  echo $url;`

Comment: I used this code. But it is giving me array to string error now at the last echo. :(

Comment: You should `echo $matches[0]`, try `print_r($matches)` to see all the URLs too.

Comment: `print_r($matches)` give me the following output. 
" (   [0] => Array
          (
          )
       [1] => Array
          (
          )
) "

Comment: Are you sure that the website is giving you a HTTP redirect and not a meta or JavaScript redirect? Can you post the URL in question?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/"user_id" . Where the user_id is taken from a input file.

Comment: @AdityaDevSharma Try it again. Add the two curl options, and make sure that the end of your URL has `?_rdr=p`. I just tried it with ID 4, and I got `zuck`.

Comment: You mean url I give CURLOPT URl to be somewhat like " https://www.facebook.com/4?rdr=p " ??  P.S. Now it's giving me unsupported browser in the Array $matches

Comment: Yes, you can put any number ID, but end the URL with that.

Comment: And don't forget the underscore, copy the url from my answer.

Comment: Had done some mistakes in url itself. Overseen the underscore. It works perfectly. Thanks a lot, my saviour. :P

Comment: Sweet, and if you're happy with this answer, feel free to click the checkmark to accept it.

Comment: Just another query, it gives unsupported browser url for some IDs. What might be the reason for it? Have checked those IDs and they exist.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: 
[Get url after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074288/get-url-after-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

As you're redirecting with PHP - one option is to set a `$_SESSION` value when the user lands, before redirecting them. e.g

```
$_SESSION['original_url'] = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
```

Then grab that on the page your redirecting to:

```
$previous_url = $_SESSION['original_url'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: As I am running the script on localhost. This returns me the localhost address only