# Get URL after Redirect on the Internet Archive

Tags: linux, curl, redirect, wget

I'm interested in programmatically saving URLs via the internet archive. The way I'm doing this https://web.archive.org/save/{myLink}.

Right now I've been using [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074288/get-url-after-curl-is-redirected) answer but it's not able to follow through all the way.

```
curl https://web.archive.org/save/{myLink} -s -L -o /dev/null -w '%{url_effective}'
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect and what happens instead or what error do you get? Please make your question more clear.

Comment: Why is this not working?

Comment: Sorry there is no error, it is just not following the redirect to completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl https://web.archive.org/save/<<<url>>> -s -I | grep Content-Location | awk '{print "http://web.archive.org/save" $2}'`