# Curl/Scrapy bypass Cloudflare 503 error redirection

Tags: linux, bash, curl, scrapy, web-crawler

I want the Curl to wait on a website for some second then save the page into a file.
Or how can I set a wait time for 'lynx' or 'curl'?

When I crawl the URLs my spider encountered with some URL that they return 503 then redirect to the next page. I know we can set redirect URL but the redirect URL and the original URL are the same.

Now I can fix my problem with this solution: For `curl` and `lynx`, I set a wait time until goes to the redirected page.
Also, I found the main problem: The Cloudflare returns us 503 redirections and It's against bot request. Also, I use from `cloudflare-scrape` module but I have this [issue](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape/issues/357) and nobody fixed it yet.

But I didn't find any example of this problem on Google or Stackoverflow.

Comment: Show us which parameters (feel free to omit the URL if it's sensitive) you use with `curl`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get final URL after curl is redirected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074288/get-final-url-after-curl-is-redirected)

Comment: I tried with both(curl & lynx) `curl -ivs --raw  https://URL`
I found the problem: It's for Cloudflare 503 redirection and I don't know how to fix it.