# finding place id or gps coordinates with a google maps url

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I've been looking at solutions to retrieve place_id or directly the gps coordinates of a place from a google maps shared url.

I want my users to simple copy paste a location link and I retrieve the coordinates of the place they want, very easily done on the long url of google maps as the coordinates are transparent (ex https://www.google.com/maps/place/Eiffel+Tower/@48.8583701,2.2919064,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x47e66e2964e34e2d:0x8ddca9ee380ef7e0!8m2!3d48.8583701!4d2.2944813!16zL20vMDJqODE?hl=en-FR&entry=ttu ).

But I'm having trouble trying to do the same kind of operation when the users use the much shorter version from the app, or the shared option on maps (ex. https://maps.app.goo.gl/GmCgwbfgzPHq1JeHA ) do you have any idea if this is possible? I've been trying to use Geocoding and place details api... but I can't quite get close to the result I'd like.

**In short I would like to get gps lat/lon from a link under this format https://maps.app.goo.gl/GmCgwbfgzPHq1JeHA using PHP HTTP request if possible and store the lat/lon in an array or at least do the same as this website https://wheregoes.com/**

---

My first guess

function unshortenURL($shortURL) {
$ch = curl_init($shortURL);

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$expandedURL = $shortURL;

if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    if ($info['http_code'] == 301 || $info['http_code'] == 302) {
        $expandedURL = $info['url'];
    }
}

curl_close($ch);
return $expandedURL;
```

}

my second choice

function unshortenURL($mapsUrl) {
//mapsUrl is only the code https://maps.app.goo.gl/**GmCgwbfgzPHq1JeHA** in bold
$apiURL = " [https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places/$mapsUrl?fields=id,displayName&key=API_KEY";](https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places/$mapsUrl?fields=id,displayName&key=API_KEY%22;)

```
$ch = curl_init($apiURL);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($response, true);

if ($data && isset($data['results'][0]['geometry']['location'])) {
    $location = $data['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];
    $latitude = $location['lat'];
    $longitude = $location['lng'];
    return array('latitude' => $latitude, 'longitude' => $longitude);
} else {
    return null; // Invalid or incomplete response
}
```

}

> {
> "error": {
> "code": 400,
> "message": "Not a valid Place ID: GmCgwbfgzPHq1JeHA\n",
> "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
> }
> }

makes sense as I'm trying to get the id with what I believed was an "id"...

third choice was basically the same but with Geocoding

Comment: If you follow the short link, you'll get the full URL...

Comment: what do you mean by follow the link? of course if I click on it on a laptop I will get the full url, but I aim to place is for my users on phone to be able to locate a place just by providing a link of that place

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074288/get-final-url-after-curl-is-redirected

Comment: In the future, be sure to include a tag for the programming language you are using. `curl` can be used in just about all programming languages, so `bash` code would be very different that `php` or `JS`. Note the number of followers for each tag you have used. Normally, you'll want a tag that will bring 100,000+ possible readers to your question. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry the curl tag was a reference of curl library of php, thank you for your comments shellter. I found a way to make it but I can not reply to my own question for now as I don't have enough credit but when ever I will be able to I will post the working code. and if you guys have some better ones I will be happy to learn for it.

MrUpsidown thank you as well for your help

Comment: Good show! ALSO, I thought of this later, the cmd-line version of  `curl` (in linux at least) supports an option `-L` that might simplify your task. `man curl` (and then you'll have to skip past a couple of other `-L`s in the file to find the documentation. I would expect that the `curl` library would also support this feature, but you'll have to find the right way to use it. (if it could help you). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer I made myself and works great for need, hope it helps other.

so basically I'm looking at a pattern (LAT/LON) in a link provided by a user. If the coordinates are presents within the provided link then we can go to the next step. Otherwise we will try to get the full link from a shortened link (using the checkRedirects function) , if a longer link exist providing us the necessary coordinates then let's keep continue other we try our luck with the extractAddressFromURL() function if any address is found we then proceed with the geocoding api from google to get out LAT/LON coordinates with the found address using the getLocationCoordinates() function.

```
$pattern = '/@(-?\d+\.\d+),(-?\d+\.\d+)/';
    if(preg_match($pattern, $activityLink, $matches)){
      $locationX = $matches['1'];
      $locationY = $matches['2'];
    } else{
                if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
                    $redirects = checkRedirects($activityLink);
                    foreach($redirects as $url){
                        if(preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches)){
                  $locationX = $matches['1'];
                  $locationY = $matches['2'];
                            break;
                } else{
                            $address = extractAddressFromURL($url);
                            $coordinates = getLocationCoordinates($address);

                            if($coordinates){
                                $locationX = $coordinates['latitude'];
                      $locationY = $coordinates['longitude'];
                                break;
                            } else{
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                }
    }
```

and here are the functions I'm calling:

```
function checkRedirects($url) {
  $redirects = [];
  $ch = curl_init($url);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  $headers = substr($response, 0, $info['header_size']);

  $lines = explode("\n", $headers);

  foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if(stripos($line, "Location:") !== false) {
      $redirects[] = trim(str_ireplace("Location:", "", $line));
    }
  }

  curl_close($ch);

  return $redirects;
}

function extractAddressFromURL($url){
  $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
  if(isset($parsedUrl['query'])){
    parse_str($parsedUrl['query'], $queryParameters);

    if(isset($queryParameters['q'])){
      $address = urldecode($queryParameters['q']);
    } elseif (isset($queryParameters['continue'])){
      $address = urldecode($queryParameters['continue']);
    } else{
      $address = 0;
    }
  } else{
    $address = 0;
  }

  return $address;
}

function getLocationCoordinates($adress){
  $encodedUrl = urlencode($adress);
  $apiURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$encodedUrl."&key=API_KEY";
  $ch = curl_init($apiURL);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $data = json_decode($response, true);

  if($data && isset($data['results'][0]['geometry']['location'])){
    $location = $data['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];
    $latitude = $location['lat'];
    $longitude = $location['lng'];
    return array('latitude' => $latitude, 'longitude' => $longitude);
  } else{
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).